# Single file output from Hive

Tags: hive, azure-blob-storage

I have a hive table that used a SerDe to store files on Azure Blob.

```
field 1 int,
field 2 string, 
field 3 struct
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

When I insert 5000 records into the table, the output consists of 5000 blobs on Azure Storage, is there a way to store the output as a single blob or even reduce the number of blobs with more records in each?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by `HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat` with the ignore key feature for writing HDFS files. Please try to specify other output formats, such as `HiveBinaryOutputFormat`.